# Multiple Webview in single activity

Tags: java, android, webview

I am creating a app that shows webview on the click of a button. Ihave an activity A that has 5 buttons. When click any of the button, it opens Activity B that has webview in it . What I want is when I click first button it should take me on activity b that contains website 1, when i click second button it take me on activity b that contains website 2 and so on. I'm passing the website url as intent. But the problem is when the second activity opens it is totally blank. I can't seem to figure out the reason.

Code below:

```
Activity A :  monsterB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Monster.class);
             i.putExtra("monsterB", Monster);
                //int x = 1;        
                startActivity(i);    
            }
        });

        naukrii.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Monster.class);
               i.putExtra("naukri", naukriaddress);
                //x=2    
                startActivity(i);    
            }
        });


Activity B :

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monster);


        WebView mons = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.monster);
        WebView nauk = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.naukri);

        String newM = "https://www.google.co.in/";
        String newN = "https://www.google.co.in/";


        String one = getIntent().getExtras().getString("monsterB");
        String hell = getIntent().getExtras().getString("naukri");



        if(one == newM) {

            mons.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            mons.loadUrl("https://www.naukri.com/");
        }        
    else if(hell == newN) {    
            nauk.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            nauk.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");    
        }

    }


Activity B.XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="nripesh.gob.Monster">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/monster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/naukri"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have made only 2 buttons so far.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into using fragments. The best option would be to switch fragments when the user decides to switch to a different website. Here you can find the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) regarding the use of fragments.

Comment: ok thankyou. No workaround possible in this code?

Comment: you can do this with single webview.. why having 2 ??

Comment: didn't worked with 1

Comment: use `i.putExtra("url", "https://www.google.co.in/");` and get it to intent in next activity...see @Munir answer i have upvoted it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change code like below just use one webview and pass  different url and load that url in web view

```
Activity A :  monsterB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Monster.class);
             i.putExtra("url", "https://www.google.co.in/");
                //int x = 1;        
                startActivity(i);    
            }
        });

        naukrii.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Monster.class);
               i.putExtra("url", "https://www.naukri.com/");
                //x=2    
                startActivity(i);    
            }
        });
```

Activity B :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monster);


    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);



    String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("url");
```

Activity B.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="nripesh.gob.Monster">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```